# Python Django, проблема на сервере

Tags: python, django

я новичек в django, имею такую проблему, на локальном сервере всё работает, я передаю данные в словаре, всегда, то есть при нажатии на кнопку передается на страницу словарь, после того как на этой странице я нажимаю на какую-либо кнопку отправляется пост запрос на сервер, с этим словарем. И вот проблема на локальном сервере всё работает а на виртуальном нет, как решить?
Код:

```
dict_of_data = {"Buttons":
                (
                    ('Добавить в', 'Удалить из', 'Изменить в', 'Просмотреть', 'Поиск'),
                    tuple_with_tables,
                    ('Удалить', 'Изменить'),
                ),
            "Buttons_for_task": ('Задание №1', 'Задание №2', 'Задание №3'),
            "Buttons_for_query": 'Запросы',
            "mode": '',
            'addon': False,
            'pagination': False,
            'user': False,
            }   # начальный словарь, кторый мы и будем таскать
def task2(request):  # для задания №2
    ids = {'Район': tuple()}  # айдишники страны и аптек
    for district in Manufacturer.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM main_district'):
        ids['Район'] = ids.get('Район') + (district.title_of_district,)
    dict_of_data.update({'ids': ids})
    return render(request, 'task2.html', dict_of_data)
```

Выше есть пример словаря, а чуть ниже подобные функции , которые работают со словарем, и при из вызове (каким-нибудь пост запросом), я пополняю или изменяю словарь, и на локальном сервере эти изменения работают, а на виртуальном, при каждом новом запросе словарь всё время переходит в свое первоначальное состояние.

Comment: Что конкретно не работает?? Сервер не запускается? Данные не передаются? Что-то другое?

Comment: Данные, на локали всё работает, в плане как, как и написано выше, я по мере работы сохраняю в этот словарик всю информацию, допустим данные которые он вводит, и после всё следующее время вожу его из пост в гет, и потом когда мне нужны эти данные я к ним обращаюсь, а после деплоя на сервер, этот словарь всё время инициализируется занного, хотя на локали такой проблемы нет. Банальные ошибки типо реинициализации в какой-то функции исключаю.

Comment: @antipups в глобальной переменной данные храните?

Comment: Нет, так как работало на локали и без этого... Ну как, она инициализированна в файле как глобальная, если вы имеете ввиду это.

Comment: @antipups Приведите, пожалуйста, код. Без него сложно сказать что-то конкретное. Вы можете сделать это, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: Прикрепил код к сообщению.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена сессиями в Джанго...